# symfony2 exceptions - don't return HTML

Tags: html, exception, symfony

I've got a symfony2 bundle where I use [jquery terminal](https://github.com/jcubic/jquery.terminal) project. It's a simple javascript console where the user passes some instructions which are executed on server side with AJAX/JSON and returned to the console and displayed. The php server scripts reads the browser-terminal request from `$GLOBALS['HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA']`.

Currently, when any request throws an error, symfony2 returns a whole HTML response. I don't want the HTML part (I'd like to display the exception message/code only).

The problem is: **symfony2 handles exceptions and catches them somewhere, embedding in HTML and returns such response. I want to modify this - the exc. may be caught, but I want no HTML included**. There is one distinct bundle, made only for the console stuff.

Comment: Paste your stack trace at dpaste.com and post it here

Comment: By default symfony only returns trace as fancy html in dev environment.

Comment: @tomas.pecserke unfortunately, I've got the same in both dev and prod environments. Do you know which config entry shall I look at?

Comment: @tkoomzaaskz Environment is configured in `web/app.php` or `web/app_dev.php` depends in which you use as entry point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact, the problem was that there was `exit` statement missing in the controller. The controller response was empty, so an exception was thrown, that a controller has to return a response. After adding `exit;` after echoing the output, the problem was gone.